# Communicate with multiple slave processes (one multiprocessing.Queue instance per slave)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have devised a way of parallelizing a certain task by distributing the work among several slave processes. So the design I've come up with is this:

- The master process creates one `multiprocessing.Queue` instance per slave process it starts.
- The master task then creates the slave processes via `multiprocessing.Process`, passing the `multiprocessing.Queue` instance this particular sub process should use to communicate with the master process.
- Next, and this is the crucial piece, the master process waits on all `multiprocessing.Queue` instances. Each time there is activity on any of the queues, I want it to wake up, read whatever message the slave process has placed in that particular queue and do something with it.

As I've pointed out, that last point is the hard part, because I can't find anything in Python's multiprocessing reference that allows me to wait on **MULTIPLE** `multiprocessing.Queue` instances at the same time. I would basically need something like Microsoft's `WaitForMultipleObjects` or the POSIX `select`, except for `multiprocessing.Queue` objects. In lieu of such functionality, I suppose I could have my master process busy-wait / poll the slave process queues with an appropriate sleep interval between individual poll cycles, but that's something I'd like to avoid unless there is no other way. Also, although I'm on a Windows machine, I'm hesitant to implement any Windows-specific solutions, as I'd like to keep things as platform-independent as possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that both the master and slaves are both readers and writers with respect to those queues.

EDIT: Just to rule out confusion, the reason why I have to enqueue work with specific sub processes and can't just pass it to an arbitrary sub process is that I'm searching dynamic links in ClearCase VOBs, and having more than one process operate on a particular VOB could actually slow things down. I want exactly one sub process per VOB, and that process should be the only one searching links in that VOB.

Comment: Why not pass all the workers the same output Queue?

Comment: @unutbu I suppose I could do that, but it would complicate things a bit because everytime one message is sent to a particular process, __all__ processes would receive it and would then have to decide whether it was intended for them or not, and if it wasn't, they'd have to place the message back into the queue. This could get pretty ugly, and I don't know that it would necessarily make things more efficient.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the Queue bidirectionally -- to send data to the workers and also for the workers to send results back to the main process. Can you instead pass 2 Queues to each worker: an (unique) input Queue and a common (i.e. shared) output Queue?

Comment: Why are they both reading and writing.  Do you need two separate queues, one for the master to issue new tasks (which are distributed to the threads by something similar to "notify one"), and another queue for threads to notify the master of a finished task? (Edit: JINX @unutbu)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yeah, my master process needs to be able to send additional work to a slave process. "Additional work" may be generated in a slave process itself, when the slave decides that this work is best done by a different process. So I want that slave to send this work back to the master, which then enqueues it with the correct slave process. Your (Kenny's and unutbu's) suggestion to use n queues that the master sends stuff on but only one that it reads from seems sound to me. :)
If you guys post your comments as an answer I would upvote them and accept the one that's first.

Comment: Generally the outgoing work is in 1 queue, and that's the whole point of having a queue for the threads to pull work from.  Only one can work on it, so the first to get it, gets it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom In my case, this first-come-first-serve policy would not work. I need to enqueue work with specific sub processes because I must ensure that each partial job is run by the process created for that particular task (I'm recursively searching dynamic links in multiple ClearCase VOBs, and 2 processes operating on the same VOB would actually slow things down).

Comment: Alright, I'll need to think about that. Would it be okay to pause the task while the subtasks are handled by the first available?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Why? I think one slaves-to-master queue and n master-to-slave queues would actually solve the problem neatly. :-)

Each time a slave finds a link into a different VOB, it sends that link back to the master (using the queue it shares with all the other slaves), which then reads it from that queue, figures out which slave should actually take care of following this link and sends it to that slave (using the queue unique to that slave). :-)

Comment: I'm modifying my answer to suggest that the workers hide their queue internally, which makes more sense if they each get one, and if tasks are assigned specifically to a worker (because it handles all the work on one VoB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a task queue

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool

but one-directional queues will be much easier to work with.

You want to issue jobs to the appropriate thread using one queue. Finished tasks can be returned in a separate queue, so that the master can wait on that. If the thread created a new task, it can be handled the same way -- the master thread can just re-issue it for the appropriate worker.

However, if each worker gets its own task queue, then there doesn't seem to be any reason to put multithreading controls on those.  They may be able to run 1 thread each internally, and have a member function to assign a new task. The master thread is more of a dispatcher which just assigns the task directly to the object which should handle it, then waits on the response queue between assigning tasks.